# Cocos2d-js to develop hybrid canvas/DOM applications

Tags: javascript, html, dom, canvas, cocos2d-js

I used cocos2d-x (c++) for one year and half and I'm comfortably with its approach. Now, I'd like to port an app in cocos-js to have something useful on browsers too.

Studying this IBM [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-htmlmark2/) I think an hybrid canvas/DOM approach will fits well for my app, anyway I'm not able to get if the cocos-js framework is able to manage it.

I've seen the canvas approach, it's clear to me, but I can't find info about the use of CSS/HTML to propose something hybrid as described in this IBM article.

Could you please provide suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at that article, but I'm not sure *what* you want to accomplish exactly.

Usually, I prefer working with everything done within Coco's drawing area, so that I can compile the game for native platforms as well as playing in the browser.

If what you want to do is discard any chance for cross-platform-compiling and let your game be played only in the browser, then there shouldn't be any issue with you using HTML elements for interacting with the game's canvas. The entirety of your game is made using JavaScript, so if you set up global objects/methods/event listeners or whatever you choose, you should be able to call your code from your objects.

Say you're making a ship game, and somewhere (in the global scope) in your game's `.js` files you've got a `var ship` with a `fire` method, there shouldn't be any problem with you having an HTML element that triggers `ship.fire();` when you click it.

On the other hand, if what you want to do is replace your game's canvas area with a "DOM renderer" (so that game sprites are DOM elements instead of drawings on a canvas), then you can't do this with Cocos. You could try [LimeJS](http://www.limejs.com/), which does let you do that (although it seems it's not been updated in some time).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Sebastiàn. I usually develop using cocos2d-x, but in app development (instead of game dev) there are things better done using an DOM approach, as described in the IBM article, as an example: text management. I'm learning cocos2d-js even to deploy on browsers and to be cross among apps and browsers, so I'd like to have a solution able to be published on different platforms. I've google it a lot, but I can't find an example to hybridize cocos2d-js with DOM elements and merge canvas with html.

Comment: Edit: you told "If what you want to do is discard any chance for cross-platform-compiling and let your game be played only in the browser". Are you telling such hybrid canvas/dom approach using cocos2d-js will loose my app ability to be used as natively as in a browser?

Comment: As far as I'm aware of, yes: albeit Cocos uses Spidermonkey for running JS code in compiled apps, it's not a real browser, so you won't have DOM elements there.